# Wordpress login to google OAuth 2?

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

*I think I might be swimming against the current here, but anyways.*

Is there any way to use the existing wordpress login credential for a USER and have it so it is use it to automatically sign into google drive?

I'm using a couple of plugins to access google drive files through wordpress, but I get ask to "Click to Authorize Google Drive" and confirm a gmail password to see the folders/files. 
I don't want the end user to know that there is a gmail account associated with it the account that is the reason I'm not using a Google OAuth to start with.

Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Use the premium version of Google Drive Embedder for WordPress

Comment: I am using the it [well the Enterprise version], but it looks like they want you  to upgrade to G-Suite and the price per license it's a bit high for my customer small business.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related